# JButton is not displayed in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

```
    if(compressedImageFilePath.exists()){
                    final String ie = Integer.toString(i);
                    JFrame mboxFrame1 = new JFrame("Optimized Image");
                    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                    ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon(compressedImageFile);
                    JLabel reader1 = new JLabel(image1);
                    mboxFrame1.setContentPane(reader1);
                    controlPanel2 = new JPanel();
                    JButton saveButton = new JButton("SAVE");
                    saveButton.setVisible(true);
                    mboxFrame1.setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height-30);
                    mboxFrame1.setResizable(true);
                    mboxFrame1.setVisible(true);
                    mboxFrame1.add(headerLabel);
                    mboxFrame1.add(controlPanel2);
                    controlPanel2.add(saveButton);
                    mboxFrame1.add(controlPanel2, BorderLayout.WEST);
     }
```

Here i am checking for a particular file. If that file exists i am creating a new Jrame and adding the Save Button to it. But the save button is not getting displayed.Where am i going wrong?

Comment: are you sure the condition is met?

Comment: You should make the frame visible only once all components have been added. EDIT : since your last edit, you no longer add the panel containing the button to your frame.

Comment: wherw is controlpanel2 added to frame?

Comment: You forget to add `controlPanel2`to your `JFrame`

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so we can understand, what's wrong. Often during creation of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) I understand what's wrong by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Please add your panel to frame. Hope that will solve the problem

Comment: Even if i add my panel to my Jframe, the button is not getting displayed

Comment: Thank You All..The Button is getting displayed

Comment: Actually the problem is with the image that is being displayed...The image over rides the save button.I want to display the Image and the save button  simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
mboxFrame1.getContentPane().add(reader1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

instead of

```
mboxFrame1.setContentPane(reader1);
```

Answer (score -1):

you don't add the JPanel you added the button to to the Jframe in any way. use a layout on your jframe and add the JPanel to the layout. easy to use is `BorderLayout`